# Blob extension validation

Tags: google-app-engine

I use the following to insert a JPEG into a blob field:

```
db.Blob(self.request.get("imgFile"))
```

How can I check if "imgFile" is a JPEG?

I dont want to let people upload EXEs, etc.

Thank

Joel

Answer (score 1):

The magic number for a JPEG file is FFD8 according to [this site](http://www.astro.keele.ac.uk/oldusers/rno/Computing/File_magic.html). What you could do is look at the two first bytes to see if they match before inserting the blob into the datastore.